# Displaying a modal view controller with transparent view above another controller while displaying navigation bar of the parent controller in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I would like to display a modal view controller with transparent background which has a small view inside, which will appear as an alert. I want to display the same above another view controller which is in a navigation stack. I tried to present my second controller in many ways like getting embedded in navigation controller, from navigation controller , second view controller itself etc . But any of these doesn't give me the same navigation bar as the parent controller. I tried adding it as a subview, but then my textfield delegate methods are not getting called. Could anyone please help me with a solution  for this. Adding some of the solutions that I tried which I got from different stack overflow answers..
1.

```
guard let alertController = /* my controller */ else { return }
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: alertController)
alertController.delegate = self
alertController.valueText = "Value"
alertController.userPhoneNumber = updatedUserPhoneNumber
navController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

2.

```
guard let alertController = /* my controller */ else { return }
alertController.delegate = self
alertController.valueText = "Value"
alertController.userPhoneNumber = updatedUserPhoneNumber
alertController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
navigationController.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

3.

```
guard let alertController = /* my controller */ else { return }
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: alertController)
alertController.delegate = self
alertController.valueText = "Value"
alertController.userPhoneNumber = updatedUserPhoneNumber
navController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
navigationController.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

4.

```
guard let alertController = /* my controller */ else { return }
alertController.delegate = self
alertController.valueText = "Value"
alertController.userPhoneNumber = updatedUserPhoneNumber
alertController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get an idea on how I can present the second controller's view. But finally I added it as a subview only. And how I got it worked is like below

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

`addChild(alertController)
 view.addSubview(alertController.view)
 alertController.didMove(toParent: self)`

and removing the same like

`willMove(toParent: nil)
 view.removeFromSuperview()
 removeFromParent()`

Please advise me if any other solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a project like this :

```
let controllerToPresent = UIViewController()
controllerToPresent.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
controllerToPresent.definesPresentationContext = true
controllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
controllerToPresent.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.8)
navigationController.visibleViewController?.present(controllerToPresent, animated: true)
// OR
navigationController.present(controllerToPresent, animated: true)
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I tried this but couldn't get proper results..

Comment: What is the result that you expect ? (I don't fully understand your expectation)

Comment: For me the second controller which is having a transparent view is covering the first controller's navigation bar. Meaning I need the same navigation bar while presenting as well. But thats not happening..

Comment: Ok, `navigationController.visibleViewController?.present(controllerToPresent, animated: true)` don't do the trick ? In my app this show the presented VC on the controller but not on the navigation